# Feed Iterator to Tensorflow Graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a `tf.data.Iterator` created with `make_one_shot_iterator()` and want to use it to train my (existing) model.

Currently my training looks like this

```
input_node = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, height, width, channels))

net = models.ResNet50UpProj({'data': input_node}, batch_size, keep_prob=True,is_training=True)

labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, width, height, 1))
huberloss = tf.losses.huber_loss(predictions=net.get_output(),labels=labels)
```

And then calling

```
sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={labels:output_img, input_node:input_img})
```

After training I can get a prediction like that:

```
pred = sess.run(net.get_output(), feed_dict={input_node: img})
```

---

Now with an iterator I tried something like this

```
next_element = iterator.get_next()
```

Passing the input data like this:

```
net = models.ResNet50UpProj({'data': next_element[0]}, batch_size, keep_prob=True,is_training=True)
```

Defining the loss function like this:

```
huberloss = tf.losses.huber_loss(predictions=net.get_output(),labels=next_element[1])
```

And executing the training as simple as while iterating over the iterator automatically with every call of this:

```
sess.run(train_op)
```

My problem is: After training I can't make any prediction. Or rather I don't know the proper way of using the iterator in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution 1: create a separate sub-graph just for inference, especially when you have layers like batch normalization and dropout (`is_training=False`).

```
# The following code assumes that you create variables with `tf.get_variable`. 
# If you create variables manually, you have to reuse them manually.
with tf.variable_scope('somename'):
    net = models.ResNet50UpProj({'data': next_element[0]}, batch_size, keep_prob=True, is_training=True)
with tf.variable_scope('somename', reuse=True):
    net_for_eval = models.ResNet50UpProj({'data': some_placeholder_or_inference_data_iterator}, batch_size, keep_prob=True, is_training=False)
```

Solution 2: use `feed_dict`. You can replace almost any `tf.Tensor`, not just `tf.placeholder` with a feed dict.

```
sess.run(huber_loss, {next_element[0]: inference_image, next_element[1]: inference_labels})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for these ideas :) May I ask how these ideas would look like in code?

Comment: @ScientiaEtVeritas: Updated.